# How to publish message to existing exchange

Tags: rabbitmq, bunny

I'm playing with Bunny, and trying to publish message to existing queue.
Unfortunately inside Bunny documentation are snipent for consumer creation but not for produser.
So for example when I try to bind to some exchange, it throws an error

```
PRECONDITION_FAILED - cannot redeclare exchange 'test' in vhost '/' with different type, durable, internal or autodelete value
```

Code:

```
conn = Bunny.new()
conn.start
ch = conn.create_channel
x = ch.direct("test")
```

Do you know why it's trying to redeclare.

Maybe I need first bind to a queue?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you tried to redeclare an exchange but you changed some of its arguments.

If you are just testing, then delete the exchange and re run your script.

We also have a set of tutorials here: http://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this problem too. If you've already setup the exchange in RabbitMQ. Make sure that you bind the exchange to your queue. You can either do that in the RabbitMQ admin or via the command line using the `rabbitmqctl` command.

Next, verify that the exchange you are using is a "direct" exchange. By default, when creating an exchange in the RabbitMQ admin it will generate a "topic" exchange. After you verify they are the same, then you should not get the error message.